Prove $E(f(X,Y)|Y)=Ef(X,t)_{t=Y}$
Let $X,Y$ be independent random variables, $f$ a bounded borel measurable function. Prove that  $E(f(X,Y)|Y)=Ef(X,t)_{|t=Y}$. My approach:
I understand the RHS as "We evaluate $Ef(X,t)$ only with respect to $X$ and then we plug $Y$ in place of $t$" Is it correct? I started with LHS as I had troubles introducing $Y$ in RHS.
LHS expands as $E(f(X,Y)|Y) = \sum_{i \in I} E(f(X,Y) \mid B_i)\mathbf{1}_{B_i}$ we can fix some $B_i$ and call it $B$ and it suffices to show that $E(f(X,Y)|B) = \mathbf{1}_{B}Ef(X,t)_{|t=Y}$.
$E(f(X,Y)|B) = \frac{1}{P(\Omega \times B)}\int_{\Omega \times B} f(X, Y) \, dP = \int_{\mathbb{R} \times B'} f(x, y)g_X(x)g_Y(y)dxdy = \int_{B'} Ef(X, y)g_Y(y)dy$. I split densities because $X,Y$ are independent and $B' = \{x: Y^{-1}(x) \in B\}$.
Here I am stuck and I dont know how to proceed. How should I continue. Any help appreciated

Your attempt does not make much sense. Do you know the general definition of conditional expectations (not involving densities, for r.v.'s which are not necessarily discrete).

Do you mean either $E(X|A) = \frac{1}{P(A)} \int_{A} XdP$ or $E(X|A) =  \int_{\Omega} XdP(\cdot |A)$?. Either way I studied the basic definitions and theorems of conditional expectation

This question is a duplicate of  Conditional Expectation of function of two RVs, one measurable, one independent.

I see but the solution in your link introduces third variable which is a method I have never seen. I would like to know if there is simpler solution.

The introduction of the third variable $Y$ is warranted directly by the very definition of the conditional expectation. Calling that a "complication" is unbelievable. If you want the simplest proof of all consider the special case $f(X,Z)=a(X)b(Z),.$ Then think of ways to generalize this to all functions $f(X,Z),.$ Hint: monotone class theorem.

Yes it seems that the linked post answers the OP question. My question is why it suffices to show that  for every bounded and A
-measurable Y
, one has E(UY)=E(f(X,Z)Y). Can you explain this to me Kurt?

As a healthy exercise take the definition of conditional expectation and prove it. For the non trivial direction use monotone or dominated convergence.
